# Does the iPad 2 location services work without WiFi?

Tags: ipad, geolocation

I'm going on holiday and downloaded some offline maps app, I was just wondering if the location services (GPS?) work without any data i.e Wifi for 3G on the iPad 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granted you have an iPad with GPS chip, the location services *do* work, but the iPad may take a bit longer to acquire the correct position. Apple explains this in a nice [support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4995).

Answer (score 1):

Location services are based on GPS, you don't need Internet connection.

<sub>Note that wifi-only iPads don't have GPS.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Location services will only work without a data connection on the iPad WiFi+3G model. The WiFi-only version doesn't include GPS, the user’s longitude and latitude are determined based on their proximity to known Wi-Fi networks on these devices. So, location services on this model depend on the connection to a WiFi network.

The WiFi+3G models have a GPS chip and therefore work without any 3G or WiFi connection but the initial locking can take much longer in this circumstance. This is why Apple uses [Assisted GPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS), which uses proximity to cellular towers and WiFi networks first to get the location locking faster.

Comment: Don't confuse A-GPS with cell tower and WLAN triangulation! A-GPS uses precalculated information to speed up TTF.